# Поиск байтовой сигнатуры в большом файле

Tags: c#

Стоит задача найти следующие сигнатуры в файле:

```
    data[i]==0x86 && data[i+2]==0x41 && data[i+4]==0x41 && data[i+76]==0x1b && data[i+78]==0x1b
и 
    data[i]==0x63 && data[i+2]==0x22 && data[i+4]==0x22 && data[i+74]==0x01 && data[i+76]==0x01
```

ранее задача уже была решена путем считывания файла в массив в памяти и поиском там. Теперь выяснилось что файлы могут иметь размер более 40 Гб. Считывание в память уже не правильно.
Эти сигнатуры мне нужно поместить в файл/массив в той последовательности, в которой они идут в исходном файле.
При чтении блоками теряю часть данных на стыке блоков.

```
        const int buffer_len = 4096;            
        byte[] Buffer = new byte[buffer_len];
        long BytesRead;
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            while ((BytesRead = fileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, buffer_len)) != 0)
            {
                //
            }
```

Блоки начинаются всегда в чётных байтах, то есть значения `data[i]==0x86` и `data[i]==0x63`, `i` будет всегда чётным. Длинна блоков 80 или 78 байт. Offset он начала файла у всех блоков такой, что не получается подобрать размер буфера, чтобы блоки не дробились.
Как правильно решить эту задачу?

Comment: А кода найдете, что надо сделать, запомнить адрес начала сигнатуры?

Comment: Сигнатуры именно эти и их две или должно работать для любых?

Comment: @aepot после нахождения их нужно скопировать в массив или файл

Comment: @Qwertiy ну в моей задаче нужны только эти сигнатуры.

Comment: @Deim можете брать ответ ниже. Он вернет список адресов всех найденных сингатур. Просто по заранее изветсному адресу сможете прочитать из файла то что нужно.

Comment: @Deim было бы не плохо, если вы примете наиболее полезный ответ.

Comment: @aepot у меня есть ещё парочка идей, на днях протестирую. Вариант гораздо проще предложенного.

Comment: @Deim StackOverflow это не сборник идеальных решений, но база знаний. Вы можете отметить ответ, даже если он не предлагает решения, но просто оказался наиболее полезным. Я не про свой ответ, а про любой из предложенных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал более простой вариант. Он не идеален, но работает корректно.

```
        static bool blockPrevBuffer = true; 
        static byte[] tempBuff;
        static long globalOffset = 0;
        const int buffer_len = 256;
        
        byte[] currBuffer = new byte[buffer_len];            

        int BytesRead;

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            while ((BytesRead = fileStream.Read(currBuffer, 0, buffer_len)) != 0)
            {                    
                Parser(currBuffer);
            }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Done.  {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");



 static void Parser(byte[] data)
    {            

        blockPrevBuffer = true;

        if (tempBuff != null)
        {
            data = tempBuff.Concat(data).ToArray();
            globalOffset -= tempBuff.Length;
            tempBuff = null;
        }

        int dataLen = data.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataLen; i++)
       {
            
            if (dataLen - i > 81)
            {
                if(data[i]==0x86 && data[i+2]==0x41 && data[i+4]==0x41 && data[i+76]==0x1b && data[i+80]==0x1b)
                {
                    i += 81;
                }
                else if (data[i]==0x63 && data[i+2]==0x22 && data[i+4]==0x22 && data[i+74]==0x01 && data[i+78]==0x01)
                {
                   i += 79;
                }
                else if (data[i]==0x63 && data[i+2]==0x22 && data[i+4]==0x22 && data[i+74]==0x01 && data[i+78]==0x01)
                {
                    i += 79;
                }
            }                
            else
            {
                if((data[i] == 0x86 || data[i] == 0x63) && blockPrevBuffer)
                {
                    tempBuff = new byte[dataLen - i];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(data, i, tempBuff, 0, tempBuff.Length);
                    blockPrevBuffer = false;
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    if (blockPrevBuffer)
                    {
                        tempBuff = null;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
       }

        globalOffset += dataLen;
        
    }
```

Идея такая. Мы ищем нужный нам блок в массиве `data` до тех пор пока в конечной части массива перестанет помещаться самый большой полный блок данных(в моём случае это 81 байт). Как только это произошло начинаем искать в конце массива данных первый байт из сигнатур, который мы ищем и плюс условие для входа в этот блок - `blockPrevBuffer` для того чтобы избежать многократного копирования в буфер конечной части массива если вдруг весь массив будет состоять из 0x63 или 0x86. копируем и помещаем в временный массив и забываем до следующего входа данных в парсер. Даже если это ошибочный блок и он не попадает в сигнатуру полностью, накладные расходы не столь велики. **В этом моменте прошу написать есть ли какой-нибудь подход позволяющий однозначно выявить сигнатуру.** При этом в переменную `globalOffset` помещаем длину массива data. эта переменная будет определять offset сначала файла целиком. Как только новые данные приходят в парсер, проверяем на null временный буфер. Если он не пуст, то помещаем данные из него перед пришедшими данными. из значения `globalOffset` нужно в этом случае отнять размер временного буфера, так как эти данные были скопированы из предыдущего  блока данных. Далее выполняется поиск в объединённом блоке данных. Получается что блок данных по сигнатуре не теряется на стыке, а переносится на начало следующего блока. И если в этом объединённом блоке данных в последних 80 байтах встретится байт 0x63 или 0x86, то начиная с этого i данные будут помещены во временный буфер и всё сначала. Время выполнения для файла размером 1Гб. примерно 9 секунд.

Answer (score 5):

Вы всегда можете держать в памяти два блока. Да, нужно будет аккуратно делать поиск, но задача решаема. То есть, при старте читаете два блока и ищите, потом первый подменяете новым с диска и меняете местами. Если все сделать аккуратно, то можно избежать копирования.

Но можно воспользоватся услугами операционной системы. Она умеет мапить файл в память. Для программиста это выглядит так, как будто весь файл загрузили в память в массив. Детали [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

А что вам мешает оставить от конца предыдущих считанных в буфер данных длину искомого блока минус 1 байт, дописать туда очередной считанный буфер - и поискать там искомую сигнатуру? И так с каждым новым считанным блоком. Никто не заставляет вас обязательно выбрасывать целиком предыдущий считанный блок, вы можете использовать данные из него и ничего тогда не потеряется.

Если вы ищете несколько разных сигнатур разного размера, то всё будет чуть сложнее, но опять же это решаемо примерно таким же методом, просто придётся чуть больше подумать.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так у меня получилось, не знаю насколько правильно, но 1 гигабайт - примерно 40 секунд на один сканер.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new List<(int, byte)>()
        {
            (0, 0x86),
            (2, 0x41),
            (4, 0x41),
            (76, 0x1b),
            (78, 0x1b)
        });

        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(new List<(int, byte)>()
        {
            (0, 0x63),
            (2, 0x22),
            (4, 0x22),
            (74, 0x01),
            (76, 0x01)
        });

        const int bufferSize = 4096;
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("file.dat"))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                {
                    byte b = buffer[i];
                    scanner1.Scan(b);
                    scanner2.Scan(b);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Scanner1: {0}", string.Join(" ", scanner1.Results));
        Console.WriteLine("Scanner2: {0}", string.Join(" ", scanner2.Results));
    }
}

public class Scanner
{
    private readonly List<(int, byte)> _signature;
    private readonly List<(long, int)> _stateMachines;
    private long _offset;

    public List<long> Results { get; }

    public Scanner(List<(int, byte)> signature)
    {
        _signature = signature;
        _stateMachines = new List<(long, int)>();
        _offset = -1;
        Results = new List<long>();
    }

    public void Scan(byte b)
    {
        _offset++;
        for (int i = 0; i < _stateMachines.Count; i++)
        {
            (long offset, int state) = _stateMachines[i];
            (int signatureOffset, byte signatureValue) = _signature[state];
            long relativeOffset = _offset - offset;

            if (relativeOffset == signatureOffset)
            {
                if (b == signatureValue)
                {
                    state++;
                    if (state == _signature.Count)
                    {
                        Results.Add(offset);
                        _stateMachines.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                    else
                        _stateMachines[i] = (offset, state);
                }
                else
                {
                    _stateMachines.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        if (b == _signature[0].Value)
            _stateMachines.Add((_offset, 1));
    }
}
```

Только следует учесть, что оно может найти пересекающиеся сигнатуры, то есть начало следующей сигнатуры ближе, чем конец предыдущей. Но это можно по идее отфильтровать из результатов.

Кстати, для ускорения процесса, можно например распараллелить вычисления в разные потоки.

*Тестил только поверхностно, возможно есть ошибки.*

Comment: Генераторами получилось бы проще.

Comment: @Qwertiy возможно, а что такое генераторы? :)

Comment: ``yield return``

Comment: @Qwertiy понял, но пока не понял с какой стороны это можно прикрутить, подумаю. Спасибо!