# Поиск адреса в памяти по паттерну в pymem

Tags: c#, python, память, pymem

Начну по порядку, по сколько вероятнее всего я неверно назову что то в кратком варианте:
Недавно начал изучать операции с памятью процессов, то есть как устроены External читы. Для начала я написал простенькую "игру" на C# где есть **переменная здоровья**, **которая изменяется после нажатия на 15** - с помощью Cheat Engine **я нашел адрес значение этой переменной, но думаю как всем известно после перезапуска будет происходить рандомизация адресного пространства и старый адрес уже будет неверным** - **как я могу получить оффсет на это значение, что не будет меняться после перезапуска?**

Дополнительно: Я нашел паттерн, но не знаю что с ним делать, если это возможно сделать как то с ним - я бы хотел посмотреть пример с помощью pymem или хотя бы что мне делать в теории

А если кратко: Как найти адрес жизни игрока, который не будет меняться после перезапуска?
А если еще и с примером: Для CS:GO имеется HazeDumper - который в итоге своей работы выдает "вечные" адреса -https://github.com/frk1/hazedumper/blob/master/csgo.json , мне же не нужно создать собственный дампер, мне нужно узнать как получить подобный адрес через CheatEngine и использовать в Pymem

```
Первый запуск:
8E 08 E4 02 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 # Повтор тут
28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0 F2 0F 01 94 F2 0F 01 # Тут 40 жизней (28 00 00)
36 F0 66 69 88 C6 2C 01 E8 F2 0F 01 DA 22 67 69


Второй запуск:
8E 08 18 01 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 # Повтор тут
28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 ED 9E 00 34 ED 9E 00 # И тут 40 жизней (28 00 00)
36 F0 66 69 78 DD E9 00 88 ED 9E 00 DA 22 67 69

Сам повтор > 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Код игры на C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int health = 100;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player heath is " +health);
            Console.ReadKey();
            health -= 15;

            if (health <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player is dead!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спрашивайте, если что то не понятно - попытаюсь объяснить по другому

Comment: Управляемый код не может быть постоянным, так как GC может перемещать данные в памяти когда посчитает нужным. То есть например вы нашли переменную, а через минуту она уедет в другое место в памяти. Про поиски сигнатур можете [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1188313/373567) посмотреть.

Comment: Вам нужно защитить переменную или я что то не понял?

Comment: @ГеннадийП мне нужно найти оффсет на переменную