# Как считывать определённые строки по позициям?

Tags: c#, строки

У меня есть файл в котором хранятся структурированные по позициям строки данных. Наглядный пример:

```
Собака Коли
Кот Виталика
Рыбка Саши
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем: каким образом считать строку с помощью её номера? К примеру мне нужно считать "Кот Виталика" который является третьей строкой в файле. Как можно реализовать считывание строки по её номеру в файле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если проект учебный и длина файла небольшая - я бы просто прочитал весь файл в массив строк:

```
string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(fullFileName);
```

И для обращения к какой-то конкретной строке использовал бы индекс массива, например, вывод строки три (проверка на выход за пределы массива опущена):

```
Console.WriteLine(content[2]);
```

Я подобным образом в простеньких скриптах модифицирую файлы, а потом записываю обратно модифицированный массив:

```
File.WriteAllLines(fullFileName, content);
```

Этот подход не единственный, мне он нравится тем, что можно использовать linq.

И если у вас файл большой то лучше читать файл поблочно.

Comment: Про крупные файлы (не знаю насколько актуально) это имелись ввиду ситуации типа описанных в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1188175/213987) и способ решения описанный @KoVadim (на базе MemoryMappedFile)

Comment: Я бы избегал использования ключевого слова `var` в однострочных примерах, так как совершенно непонятно, какой тип возвращает метод `ReadAllLines`, судя по следующему примеру, что-то с индексатором: "список, массив, коллекция, коллекция чего?" надо лезть в документацию, чтобы узнать. А если бы указали тип явно, в документацию лезть бы не пришлось.

Comment: @aepot Такое себе замечание, ибо с `var` почти всегда понятно, что это за тип, а в этом случае понятно даже по описанию "Прочитать все строки" - строкой в C# является `string`, значит это `string[]`. Также без проблем можно написать `content.` и увидеть тип, либо банально навести на название и увидеть, что за тип. Так что удобно всегда повторять типы, дерзайте, дело ваше, но не учите других, как им было бы удобней и понятней. Вот серьезно, не поверите, за все время, что я сижу на C#, у меня не было проблем с понятиям что это за тип у меня в `var`...

Comment: Ну, смысл есть: в онлайне мышкой на тип не наведёшь. Я видел подобный стиль, когда мы пишем var только когда тип виден (в строке есть new и тип), а из методов не пишем никогда var. Сам же - да, либо помню для типовых вещей какой тип, либо мне не особо критично помнить это. Ну и если уж что-то не работает - навожу курсор.

Comment: О чем и речь, `var` это просто удобней, вот и все и во многих случаях это не доставляет проблем. А онлайн, тут я уверен, что автор вопроса пойдет копировать пример в студию и будет там разбираться, здесь ему уже сказали в ответе "весь файл в массив строк" и этого как по мне достаточно (хотя я еще не встречал на SO людей, которым не понятно было что находится в `var`), а остальное у него придет с опытом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ никаких проблем, это была скорее рекомендация, а не замечание. Применение рекомендации на усмотрение автора ответа (я не стал редактировать ответ). И если вам понятно, что и где, и я наверняка знаю, что за тип возвращает этот метод, но к сожалению не все посетители так же ориентируются а методах класса `File` как мы. Поэтому визуально лучше так, как указано в ответе сейчас.

Comment: @aepot Ну, я от вас видел что-то по типу: "Не приятно читать, когда сплошные var", по этой причине я лично расцениваю это больше, как претензию с вашей стороны к людям, которые используют их. Если не прав, уж извините, просто мое видение ситуации. Да и как рекомендация это похоже больше на: "Не держите вилку правой рукой, держите левой!", что каждый человек может расценивать по-разному. Тут дело вкуса, дело привычки, дело удобства и как я написал выше, проблем для новичка это вряд ли составит. Так что стоит-ли навязывать что-то одно подобными решениями? Я думаю, что нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если строки не фиксированной одинаковой длины, то вариант один - читать файл подряд начиная с самого начала и считать строки, пока не дойдёте до нужной. Если бы строки были фиксированной длины, то можно было бы отпозиционироваться сразу на нужную позицию через `seek`.

Comment: Это лучший вариант, если нам надо прочитать одну строку (особенно уточнение, что при строках фиксированной длины мы можем сразу облегчить жизнь используя seek). Дал альтернативный вариант, когда читаем файл весь (походит только для файлов небольших размеров и когда подразумевается, что будем работать не с одной строкой, а с несколькими - это экономит дисковые операции, читаем один раз)