# Проверка массива байт на сигнатуры

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть массив байт размером 2048 байт.
Этот массив попадает на фабрику в которой нужно проверить этот массив на совпадение сигнатур:

```
byte[] Array = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x39, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x35, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x30, 
            0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x33, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x37, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x35, 0x00, 0x35, 0x00, 
            0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0xC3, 
            0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x2C, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x2C, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0xC5, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x35 };
```

сигнатуры я определил так:

```
byte[,] signature2 = new byte[,] { { 0x01, 0x30 }, { 0x02, 0x00 }, { 0x03, 0x39 }, { 0x04, 0x00 }, { 0x05, 0x31 } };
```

где первый элемент двухмерного массива - это смещение, второй элемент значение которое ожидаем увидеть по этому смещению.

Выполняю проверку так:

```
private static bool Check(byte[] bytes, byte[,] pattern)
    {
        int indexesLen = pattern.GetLength(0);
        
        for(int i=0; i< indexesLen; i++)
        {
            if (bytes[pattern[i, 0]] != pattern[i, 1])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

сама фабрика выглядит примерно так:

```
        if (Check(Array, signature1))
        {
            // 
        }
        else if(Check(Array, signature2))
        {
              //
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
```

Всего сигнатур около 60 штук. Смещение у сигнатур не всегда по порядку. То есть может быть 1-й байт, 6 - байт и 8 - байт и тд. Также длина сигнатуры может быть от 6 до 14 байт.
Проверять нужно очень быстро, поэтому использовал массив. При использовании readonly span наблюдается деградация скорости. с массивом байт - 3900 ticks, readonly span - 11000 ticks. на одну проверку. Можно ли выполнять эту проверку как-то по другому? с сохранением скорости, разумеется. Интересуюсь не потому что меня этот вариант не устраивает, а с целью расширить кругозор. Задача не уникальная и скорее всего её уже решали и скорее всего что-то подобное написано у Кнута, просто я ещё до 3-го тома не добрался...

Comment: Мммм... А зачем портянка однотипных if если можно собрать в массив и проитерировать?

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1188175/373567?

Comment: Кстати, я так и не понял, почему вам не зашло предложенное мной решение. Вы не отписали комментарий и не приняли ответ, никакой реакции. А я ведь полдня его писал для вас.

Comment: @AK можете поподробней про массив и итерацию.

Comment: @aepot тот вопрос был про файл и скорее про внешний поиск. тут в моём понимании немного другое. Про Ваш ответ, я его попробовал использовать, но у меня что-то не заработало как нужно, возможно я не верно понял ваше решение.  В итоге решил по своему.

Comment: Так надо было написать, что и как, решили бы. Ваше решение посмотрел, выглядит странно. Такое ощущение, что при любом изменении сигнатур или данных придется переписывать код.

Comment: `с массивом байт - 3900 ticks, readonly span - 11000 ticks` - версия .NET какая? В релизном билде замеряли? Benchmark.NET пробовали?

Comment: `Можно ли выполнять эту проверку как-то по другому?` сигнатуры задаете прямо в коде или грузите из внешнего источника? Как это в целом работает? Насколько часто смещение по порядку, насколько часто с разрывами? Как вы задаете смещение, если начало сигнатуры дальше, чем 256 байт от начала? Ведь максимальное смещение у вас сейчас 255.

Comment: @aepot .NET 4.8 замеры делал в Debug mode. Benchmark не пробовал. Сигнатуры задаются в коде.  смещение по порядку и с разрывами примерно 50/50 дальше 128 байт смещение только для 2-х случаев из 60. по этим случаям приходится проверять конец массива, так как заголовок для этого случая расположен в конце массива

Comment: `Span<T>` и `ReadOnlySpan<T>` в 4.x работают раз в 5 медленнее, чем в .NET Core и выше. Потому что в Framework они эмулированы програмно, написаны на C# для обратной совместимости, а в новых .NET имеют свою собственную сильно оптимизированную реализацию на низком уровне, и JIT компилятор генерит для них совершенно другой код. Так что они и должны быть медленнее у вас. Если нужна производительность, переносите проект на .NET 5. Даже ничего не переписывая, оно быстрее работать будет. К сожалению, для Framework 4.8 у меня предложений по оптимизации нет, он уже слишком старый и медленный.

Comment: И да, производительность замерять надо **только** в Release билде, и никак иначе. Дебаг никогда правду не покажет, потому что разный код воспринимается и обрабатывается отладчиком по-разному в плане задержек. Еще неоптимизированный код сам по себе работает не так как оптимизированный.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/214841/ тут описан самый быстрый способ сравнения массивов через unsafe-метод. Храните сигнатуры удобно: struct Signature { public int Offset; public byte[] Sequence; } А если хотите ещё быстрее - используйте Vector<T>, но это требует подготовки большого числа массивов заранее.

Comment: @Blackmeser векторизация - штука, требующая непрерывного потока данных, в противном случае расходы ресурсов на полготовку данных будут просто выше, чем выйгрыш от SIMD. Я не вижу где можно применить вектор эффективно. Быть может AVX-512 с аппаратной загрузкой из разных участков памяти помог, но этот набор инструкций редко пока в процессорах встречается.

Comment: @aepot вектор можно эффективно применить, если по каждой сигнатуре у нас есть уже подготовленные фрагменты из большого числа файлов. А если мы слушаем сеть и буквально во всех подключениях ищем сигнатуры, как делает это WireShark - вектор будет полезнее, имхо.